# How to enable logging from a dependency jar in the current project in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jar, java.util.logging

I have a dependency jar in my current project where i need to enable logging from that jar.

I have included logging.properties in the Home/lib folder of my project but the console is still not logging from that dependency jar. In the logging.properties file I have set the level as info for that package.

org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.level=INFO

In the dependency class which is being called I have logged using log.INFO.

Comment: Does `logging.properties` available in classpath ?

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409342/9169461. Hope this helps

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409342/9169461). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have answered a similar question. Please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409342/9169461). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the file from which you will be reading the properties using

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myfile
```