# Log file not getting generated from dependent JAR application

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

I have a maven application which generates a JAR and used Apache logging in it. When I ran the JAR standalone, log file is getting generated successfully.

Now using this JAR file as dependent in another Maven Spring web application, in which the JAR file classes are consumed.

But while running the application, could see that only WAR file logs are getting generated and not the dependent JAR log files.

Is this the expected behaviour? or am I missing any configuration etc ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using apache logging in your war project?  How are you configuring the logging in the jar?

Comment: @Deadron yes am using apache log4j in my WAR project. Both in my WAR and JAR configurations are added in log4j properties file and the properties file names are different.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the logger tag with the package name of your dependent jar in the logback file (ex. logback.xml)

```
<logger name="com.your.project.package">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Thanks! This gave me an idea. I added some different configs.
```
<category name="com.your.project.package">
                <priority value="info"/>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set the logger by package in application.properties?

Example:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web= DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate= ERROR
```